# How to calculate smoothed moving average using Postgres SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, moving-average

I have a table in my Postgresql DB that has the fields: `product_id, date, sales_amount`.
I am calculating a simple moving average for the last 1 week using the below SQL

```
SELECT date,  
       AVG(amount)
       OVER(PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS avg_amount
FROM sales
```

How can I calculate a smoothed moving average(smma) instead the simple moving average above? I have found that the formula is `smma_today = smma_yesterday * (lookback_period - 1) + amount) / lookback_period`
but how to translate to SQL?
A CTE or function or query approach suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?  What is "lookback_period"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks for [Mike Organek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65172589/2849004) that showed the way forward for the calculation was a recursive approach on the query. I am starting off with the simple moving average at some distant point in the past and thereafter using the smoothed average daily which has given us exactly what we needed

```
with recursive my_table_with_rn as 
(
SELECT 
    product_id,
    amount,
    sale_date,
    row_number() over (partition by product_id order by sale_date) as rn
FROM sale
where 1=1
    and sale_date > '01-Jan-2018'
    order by sale_date
),
rec_query(rn, product_id, amount, sale_date, smma) as 
(
    SELECT 
        rn,
        product_id,
        amount,
        sale_date,
        AVG(amount)  OVER(PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS smma --first entry is a simple moving average to start off
        from my_table_with_rn 
        where rn = 1
    union all
    select 
        t.rn, t.product_id, t.amount, t.sale_date, 
        (p.smma * (7 - 1) + amount) / 7 -- 7 is the lookback_period; formula is smma_today = smma_previous * (lookback_period - 1) + amount) / lookback_period
    from rec_query p
    join my_table_with_rn t on 
    (t.rn = p.rn + 1 AND t.product_id = p.product_id)
)   
SELECT * FROM rec_query
```

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure you will need recursion since your formula depends on using a value calculated for a previous row in the current row.

```
with recursive mma as (
  (select distinct on (product_id) *, ddate as basedate, 
          amount as sm_mov_avg
     from smma
    order by product_id, ddate)
  union all
  select smma.*, mma.basedate,
         (  mma.sm_mov_avg
          * least(smma.ddate - mma.basedate, 6)
          + smma.amount) / least(smma.ddate - mma.basedate + 1, 7)
    from mma
         join smma on smma.product_id = mma.product_id
          and smma.ddate = mma.ddate + 1
)
select ddate, product_id, amount, round(sm_mov_avg, 2) as sm_mov_avg,
       round(
         avg(amount) over (partition by product_id
                               order by ddate
                        rows between 6 preceding
                                 and current row), 2) as mov_avg
  from mma;
```

Please note how the smooth moving average and the moving average begin to diverge after you reach the lookback of seven days:

```
 ddate      | product_id | amount | sm_mov_avg | mov_avg
 :--------- | ---------: | -----: | ---------: | ------:
 2020-11-01 |          1 |      8 |       8.00 |    8.00
 2020-11-02 |          1 |      4 |       6.00 |    6.00
 2020-11-03 |          1 |      7 |       6.33 |    6.33
 2020-11-04 |          1 |      9 |       7.00 |    7.00
 2020-11-05 |          1 |      4 |       6.40 |    6.40
 2020-11-06 |          1 |      6 |       6.33 |    6.33
 2020-11-07 |          1 |      4 |       6.00 |    6.00
 2020-11-08 |          1 |      1 |       5.29 |    5.00
 2020-11-09 |          1 |      8 |       5.67 |    5.57
 2020-11-10 |          1 |     10 |       6.29 |    6.00
 2020-11-11 |          1 |      8 |       6.54 |    5.86
 2020-11-12 |          1 |      4 |       6.17 |    5.86
 2020-11-13 |          1 |      3 |       5.72 |    5.43
 2020-11-14 |          1 |      2 |       5.19 |    5.14
 2020-11-15 |          1 |      5 |       5.16 |    5.71
 2020-11-16 |          1 |      8 |       5.57 |    5.71
 2020-11-17 |          1 |      4 |       5.34 |    4.86
 2020-11-18 |          1 |     10 |       6.01 |    5.14
 2020-11-19 |          1 |      5 |       5.86 |    5.29
 2020-11-20 |          1 |      3 |       5.46 |    5.29
 2020-11-21 |          1 |      3 |       5.10 |    5.43
 2020-11-22 |          1 |      9 |       5.66 |    6.00
 2020-11-23 |          1 |      7 |       5.85 |    5.86
 2020-11-24 |          1 |      1 |       5.16 |    5.43
 2020-11-25 |          1 |     10 |       5.85 |    5.43
 2020-11-26 |          1 |      7 |       6.01 |    5.71
 2020-11-27 |          1 |      8 |       6.30 |    6.43
 2020-11-28 |          1 |      8 |       6.54 |    7.14
 2020-11-29 |          1 |      1 |       5.75 |    6.00
 2020-11-30 |          1 |      9 |       6.21 |    6.29
```

[Working Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=cb58546e34d39334683e0f7dc2c62311)